# Get the second highest value with Standard SQL

Tags: sql

Consider a database with one table called `user` having two fields:

```
"id" (type: INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY)
"name" (type: VARCHAR(32))
```

Write a standard SQL query which retrieves the second highest value of `id` from the `user` table. The value returned should be represented using the column name `id`.

Which is standard SQL?

`select id from user order by id desc limit 1,1;`

`select user.id as id from user order by user.id desc limit 1,1;`

If both of them were wrong, and then correct answer?

Comment: The correct answer is to either use an ORM, or not change your database.

Comment: One big problem with your question is that 'Standard SQL' is sort of mythological...people talk about it, but it doesn't really exist.  yes there are SQL standards, but nothing precicely implements any one of them.  Note how this question got closed: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5871183/456188

Comment: `OFFSET` combined with `FETCH FIRST` is the standard SQL answer.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, neither `TOP` nor `LIMIT` are defined by the SQL standard (at least I could not find it).

So the only pure standard solution would be to use window functions:

```
select *
from (
   select id, 
          row_number() over (order by id desc) as rn
   from "user"
) as t 
where rn = 2;
```

Comment: Lovely code, I use a method like this to send back data to gridview so as not to pull all rows back

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX( id) FROM user where id !=( SELECT max (id) FROM user )
```

Comment: it will not return everything.it will return only the second highest . try it

Comment: to filter i'm using max(id) in main query

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    secondhighest.id
from 
    "user" highest
    left join "user" biggerthanhighest on 
        biggerthanhighest.id > highest.id
    left join "user" secondhighest on
        highest.id > secondhighest.id
    left join "user"  biggerthansecondhighest on
        biggerthansecondhighest.id > secondhighest.id and
        biggerthansecondhighest.id < highest.id
where
    biggerthanhighest.id is null and
    biggerthansecondhighest.id is null
```

will avoid top and subqueries.  might be reasonably fast on really large tables?

Comment: That's not standard SQL (standard SQL uses double quotes `"` for identifiers)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 id
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 id
FROM user
ORDER BY id DESC) a
ORDER BY id
```

This is pretty standard as well I would think.

Comment: `TOP` is not part of the SQL standard.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 "id" FROM (SELECT TOP 2 "id" FROM "user" ORDER BY "id" DESC) AS "wt" ORDER BY "id"
```