# Write a query to get name and marks of second highest scorer for every course

Tags: sql, database

Write a query to get name and marks of second highest scorer for every course.

[image]

Comment: Please don't expect us to do your work for you. And please try searching before you post a question so you aren't wasting everybody's time. If you did that, you would have found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333990/get-the-second-highest-value-with-standard-sql?rq=1

Comment: I have answer but I am not 100% confident so that I post this Question on Upwork. I know your time is so much important and I really appreciate your comment.

Comment: update you question with what you have

Answer (score 2):

This will give you second highest marks

```
Select
  (SELECT MAX(Marks) FROM Marks
  WHERE Marks NOT IN 
  (SELECT MAX(Marks) FROM Marks)) AS 'Second Highest'
  from Marks
```

Answer (score 0):

WITH MarksCTE AS
   (
   Select DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CourseID ORDER BY Marks desc) as              Rank, m.Marks,c.Name as Course,s.Name as Student
   From Marks as M
   Inner Join Student as s on S.Id = M.StudentID 
   Inner Join Course as c on c.Id = M.CourseID
  )
  Select Marks,Course,Student from  MarksCTE where Rank = 2